# What is the significance of the robot names in Interstellar?

Tags: character, analysis, interstellar

In *Interstellar*, robots are quite unconventional looking (which I have [discussed already here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/27141/why-the-robots-were-so-unconventional)), but they all have quite catchy names like TARS, KIPP, CASE and PLEX (in game).

So what is the significance of these names?

Nolan doesn't seem like a guy who will name the robots randomly and it seems there should be a meaning behind those names.

Comment: What does "in game" refer to?

Comment: @unor there is a game about the film too, referring to that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been addressed over on [SF&F](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72508/why-are-tars-and-case-named-as-such) although not fully.

A [Wired](http://www.wired.com/2014/11/interstellar-droids/) article speaking with Nolan mentions that they're not named after anything.

> The main bot, named TARS (which doesn’t stand for anything), might as well be a distant cousin of 2001‘s monolith. Then again, nothing in Nolan’s world(s) is what it seems. “When I let my kids play with the model, open it up, see different combinations,” he says, “they started getting really excited.” Let’s peek inside the box.

There is some fan discussions [here](http://interstellarfilm.wikia.com/wiki/CASE) with a few theories, but nothing concrete in terms of information.

TARS could be an anagram of STAR, KIPP could be a reference to the physicist [Kip Thorne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kip_Thorne), but these are just conjectures.